# Support submitting a new answer to a closed question with an incorrect answer

Tags: feature-request, edits, voting, closed-questions

In searching for a way to stay connected to a server via SSH when the server had a 10 minute timeout, I came across this Stack Overflow post:

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390710/mac-terminals-how-to-keep-alive*

The question has been closed (not removed) for being off topic. The question matches my needs and an answer has been supplied with over 50 upvotes! Wow it must be the correct answer!? But it is not. The answer is incorrect.

The original question looked like this

---

You can define that you want to keep the connection alive in the ssh configuration. You have to edit (create if it does not exist):

```
~/.ssh/config
```

Add these two lines to it:

```
ServerAliveInterval 300
ServerAliveCountMax 36
```

The value `ServerAliveInterval` defines the interval in seconds between two noop operations that keeps to connection alive. It is 5 minutes in this case. 
The value `ServerAliveCountMax` defines the number of times the noop is sent. In this case the connection will be kept open for 3 hours.

---

However, this incorrect - The serverAliveCountMax variable doesn't specify a count of packets sent - it's just the number of times you try to connect once the server goes down. The serverAlive will run indefinitely - it will not stop after count * interval amount of seconds....

I was able to edit the answer to be correct, but this goes against the Stack Overflow mentality of best answer voting since I am forced to only edit the wrong answer, and cannot get credit for creating the correct answer, or fixing the answer in a different submission (without the comments on the incorrect answer).

**Do you feel this workflow is broken? Should we be able to suggest a correct answer if an answer is incorrect - allowing voting to show it is indeed incorrect?**

Note that if you click the link at the top of this post, you will see my corrected, edited answer (pending peer review).

Comment: The question you're highlighting is not a programming question. The fact that it even exists on Stack Overflow is a historical accident. If you'd like to help propagate what you believe to be a correct solution to the problem, I would strongly suggest making a post _on the appropriate site_. ([Posting a question yourself in order to share the answer is supported](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463).) That could be either [SU] or [Apple.SE], in this case. (Note that there is what seems to be a closely-related question [already on the latter site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/36690/).)

Comment: Migration is also possible, although it's unlikely in this case since the question is more than a few months old.

Comment: What do you suppose *closed* means?

Comment: Better solution-  this question doesn't belong here, lets just vote to delete it.  Then its wrong answer won't bother people (assuming the answer is wrong, which I'm not qualified to do).

Answer (score 14):

Find a site where the question is actually on topic and ask the question there.

If we let people continue to post answers to closed questions then there'd be no point in closing questions in the first place.

If you see an answer that you feel is incorrect, or otherwise unhelpful, you can downvote it and optionally comment with what you feel is problematic about it.  Editing it to completely change its content to what you feel is right is inappropriate and a violation of the site's editing policies.

Comment: I must disagree. People search stackoverflow for answers irrespective of if the question is closed. They will find their question, closed or not closed, and use the highly upvoted incorrect answer - assuming it is correct. If the question is closed, you cannot fix this. So now everyone who views that post, will be misled for all future views of that post. For some posts, this is tens of thousands of people being mislead reading the wrong answer to a closed post. A suitable correction should be supported other than a comment.

Comment: @cgn This doesn't really have anything to do with closure; assuming you're actually correct about the post's problems, the issue is a bad post getting 50 upvotes, and has nothing to do with its closure.  Even if you could post a new answer, it would do anything to change the fact that there'd be an answer with 50 more upvotes sitting right at the top of the list.

Comment: Not necessarily (although its a fair point), my proposed solution creates the potential that the correct answer would get upvoted more-so than the incorrect answer. If the correct answer highlighted how the incorrect answer was incorrect - it would increase the likelihood of the correct answer being upvoted to the top answer - saving a lot of headache for future viewers.

Comment: @cgn The existing answer can be downvoted down if it's really completely worthless, and the question can be deleted if it's found to not be valuable.  At this point though it would appear that quite a lot of people have found the content valuable, so there doesn't seem to be much evidence supporting your position.

Comment: The reason why people have found the content valuable is because the solution works! However, it doesn't work for the right reasons and is causing people's computers to check with the server 36 times when its down. It also makes people think that the connection will time out after count * interval amount of time, but this doesn't actually happen. The question is upvoted because its not well-known. The documentation however, validates that the question is incorrect:

Comment: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config

Comment: @cgn And yet you haven't even bothered to comment on the answer to explain that.

Comment: I extensively edited the question. I'm trying to improve stackoverflow, we are not discussing my personal actions - but the workflow of stackoverflow. Currently there are wrong answers being used and no way to submit a correct answer once the question is closed. People are being misinformed - I want to improve this...

Comment: @cgn And you've been told that such edits are inappropriate, and your edit has (correctly) been rejected.  Fundamentally the content is off topic.  You're functionally asking for everything that's currently off topic to be considered on topic.  SE works in no small part due to it's scoping.  Off topic content is closed.  You do have several means to provide feedback on the post, if you want to.

Comment: Can we please focus on Stackoverflow and the point of the post - not on me. People are viewing incorrect answers to closed questions.

Comment: I understand that. But there remains the issue that people are being misinformed and there is no good way to fix this... I will comment as you suggested. But my comment is a tiny little box under a big highlighted checked answer.

Comment: @cgn And you have the ability to provide that feedback if you want.  What you don't have the ability to do is reopen every single off topic question.  If the community generally agrees that the content is worthless, it can be deleted.

Comment: I'm sure the community feels its not worthless (based on the number of votes). Also based on the upvotes, the community also does not realize the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @cgn Indeed.  As frustrating as it can be, just because you think some content is terrible doesn't mean everyone else will, and you don't have the ability to overrule everyone else's opinions.  I'm aware of how frustrating that can be, but it's the reality of the situation (as is so often the case in life, even outside of SE).

Comment: It is clear that I am powerless to pursue this further. Upon your suggestion, I have added comments that communicate the issues with the post and help address the confusion of the user who commented. Hopefully this will suffice and users will notice it. Thanks for responding in these comments.

Comment: I also am strongly saddened that I'm legitimately trying to improve learning and eliminate users from reading incorrect answers and getting downvoted. This has been frustrating in more ways than one.

Comment: @cgn did you notice that your rep did not change one bit due to those downvotes?  On meta, rep does not exist.  And voting is **sometimes** used to express agreement or disagreement with proposals.  In this case, the downvotes could be saying "we don't agree that this feature is needed".

Comment: @psubsee2003 ahh - thank you so much!

Comment: @cgn meta can be very odd and scary if you aren't prepared.  It seems very negative, but once you understand it, it can be very welcoming.  This can be a fun read from the Uber Meta (which does have rep unlike this site): [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying_)